# Reject values while using Maps.uniqueIndex with Guava

Tags: java, functional-programming, guava

I'd like to know whether it's possible to discard some values when we use the Guava method.

```
public static Function<Locale, String> GET_LANGUAGE = new Function<Locale, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Locale input) {
        return StringUtils.isBlank(input.getLanguage()) ? "NO_LANGUAGE" : input.getLanguage();
    }
};

Maps.uniqueIndex(availableLocales, GET_LANGUAGE);
```

I know I could have used a multimap since many locales can have the same language but it fits my needs actually.

For exemple, I'd like the locales without any language not to be in the output map. As I can't return null or things like that, I redirect the locales with non-relevant language to key "NO_LANGUAGE". The problem is that the value can still be retrieved.

Is there some kind of "/dev/null" map key, or will I always need to do some filter before/after using a predicate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Guava contributor here.

Nope.  Do a filter...or possibly more efficiently, just build the map yourself, and don't use `Maps.uniqueIndex` entirely.  It's probably simpler and shorter that way anyway.

Comment: yeeees i know but i love guava :)

Comment: I'm glad that you do -- I start working full-time on Guava in just over a month -- but Guava can't really turn Java into a language in which functional programming is a sane approach in the general case.

Comment: that's why i'm learning Scala. The pain is the verbosity of anonymous inner classes but once the classes are created that's fine. Check my code http://pastebin.com/KNe5LxAP Finally Scala offers the same kind of thing like Option getOrElse. What about Either in Guava?

Comment: As briefly discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/guava-discuss/rsVLDmTtrYM/gdAr00gkpRYJ), there's not really any _nice_ way to do something useful with `Either` in pure Java.

Comment: FYI, on lines 46 and 65 of your linked code, you don't need to check if the list returned by `Multimap.get` is null -- since `Multimap.get` never returns null.  I'm still not sure why you would want to use an `Optional` as a substitute for the empty list, but eh.

Comment: Thanks this is was i though but was not sure for the null. Btw returning an optional is useful because it permits to use "or()" on the main algorithm which is more elegant and is not provided by an empty list. I think using Optional is nice with empty list particularly on such cases where an empty list means the same thing as a null list: result not found

Answer (score 4):

I want to add that if [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=968) is resolved you'll be able to do:

```
ImmutableMap<String, Locale> index = FluentIterable.from(availableLocales)
    .filter(NOT_BLANK_LANGUAGE)
    .uniqueIndex(GET_LANGUAGE);

public static Predicate<Locale> NOT_BLANK_LANGUAGE = new Predicate<Locale>() {
  @Override
  public boolean apply(Locale input) {
    return !StringUtils.isBlank(input.getLanguage());
  }
};

public static Function<Locale, String> GET_LANGUAGE = new Function<Locale, String>() {
  @Override
  public String apply(Locale input) {
    return input.getLanguage();
  }
};
```

which, with Java 8 lambdas, will be even more concise.

Comment: Yes actually what i wanted to know is if i can do it without creating a predicate. Finally this is what i've done